# Can Twilio provide any location data for incoming calls or sms?

Tags: gps, location, twilio

I'm setting up a new time clock-type application for one of my clients. We need the worker's location whenever the worker calls in to confirm they are at the proper job site.

So I found some services like this one http://timesheetmobile.com/ which claim to be able to:  "Unlike other location applications that run on the phone, Timesheet Mobile utilizes the carrier's secure network (cell towers) to identify the location of the employee's phone." They claim this works with any cellphone - no app required.

Is this kind of location data available from Twilio for either incoming calls or SMS?

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on a specialized Twilio forum, than here. You could ask Twilio support your question here: https://www.twilio.com/help/contact

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, you can't use sms for geolocation. At best you could use any number of databases to find out the general area that the senders phone number is from, based on their  areacode/exchange but not where they were when they sent it.